# How can i get data stored in node persist storage using get Request?

Tags: node.js, express, backend

i stored 3 fields in node persist database using storage set item function

Now i want to get all fields in database

But when i send request of ID only one name comes up

How can i get gpa too ?

and how can i get all the data stored in database together?

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
const storage = require('node-persist');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
storage.init()

app.get("/student/:id" , async(req,res) =>{
    res.send(await storage.getItem(req.params.id));
});

app.get("/student/:allStudents" , async(req,res) =>{
    res.send(await storage.getItem('student_id' , 'student_name'));
});

app.post("/student" , jsonParser ,async(req,res) =>{
    const {student_id , student_name, gpa} = req.body;
    await storage.setItem(student_id , student_name , gpa);
    res.send('Student Added')
})

app.listen(5000 , ()=> {
    console.log("Server has started")
});
```

i want to get all data stored using allStudent end point

Comment: It seems you don't use the API correctly. For example, `async setItem(key, value, [options])`, the third parameter is options. So you didn't store the `gpa` data in storage correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by

```
//Retrieving All Student Data from the storage by Id 

app.get('/allStudents', async (req, res) => {
    let htmlCode = `<h1>All students data!</h1>`;
    students = await storage.values();
    for (let i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
        //Displaying the result in HTML Format
        htmlCode += `
            <h2>Student id: ${students[i].id}</h2>
            <h3>Name: ${students[i].name}</h3>
            <h3>GPA: ${students[i].gpa}</h3><br/><br/>
        `
    }
    res.send(htmlCode);
})
```